# Deduce template parameter type name and generate conjuct variable

Tags: c++

There is some legacy COM code in Windows platform, and want to port to Linux, but __uuidof() can't be used under gcc

For most of cases, it can be solved with the below code to solve it.

```
#define __uuidof(T)  IID_ ##T
```

but for some cases, it can't work, for example,

```
template <class T>
HRESULT QueryInterface(IUnknown* p, T** ppv)
{
    return p->QueryInterface(__uuidof(T), (void**)ppv);
}
```

So I'd like to implement a template function to let it work, like as,

```
template <class T>
GUID __uuidof()
{
    return IID_ ##typeof(T);
}
```

How to implement it and let it work exactly with a general solution? It can't be guaranteed there exists a static member _IID in each interface definition.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)?

Comment: typeid can work during compile-time to get a conjunct variable like as preprocessing directives?

Comment: Sadly `typeid` does not produce a compile time usable value, but it would still solve your problem in the example cases you showed.

Comment: Really? Can you show me a simple code clip? I think if typeid can't work during compile time, it can't generate the conjunct variable based on it.

Comment: You can just let `GUID` be `std::type_info` and call `return p->QueryInterface(typeid(T), (void**)ppv);`. Turning a `std::type_info` into a string is tricky, because the obvious solution of just using `type_info.name()` does not guarantee unique strings for different types. Maybe you can use [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) for that.

Comment: This issue is solved in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977244/how-can-i-define-an-uuid-for-a-class-and-use-uuidof-in-the-same-way-for-g

Comment: If you feel like this post solves your question you should be able to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the post [How can I define an UUID for a class, and use __uuidof, in the same way for g++ and Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977244/how-can-i-define-an-uuid-for-a-class-and-use-uuidof-in-the-same-way-for-g) Although I can't compile the code successfully in that post, but the idea is good, after following the idea mentioned in it, and a sample code which can be compiled and run well is given to solve the __uuidof under gcc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory.h>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

#define nybble_from_hex(c)      ((c>='0'&&c<='9')?(c-'0'):((c>='a'&&c<='f')?(c-'a' + 10):((c>='A'&&c<='F')?(c-'A' + 10):0)))
#define byte_from_hex(c1, c2)   ((nybble_from_hex(c1)<<4)|nybble_from_hex(c2))

typedef struct _GUID {
    unsigned long  Data1;
    unsigned short Data2;
    unsigned short Data3;
    unsigned char  Data4[ 8 ];
} GUID;

static GUID GUID_NULL = {0, 0, 0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0}};

#ifndef _REFGUID_DEFINED
#define _REFGUID_DEFINED
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define REFGUID const GUID &
#else
#define REFGUID const GUID * __MIDL_CONST
#endif
#endif

__inline int IsEqualGUID(REFGUID rguid1, REFGUID rguid2)
{
    return !memcmp(&rguid1, &rguid2, sizeof(GUID));
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
__inline bool operator==(REFGUID guidOne, REFGUID guidOther)
{
    return !!IsEqualGUID(guidOne,guidOther);
}

__inline bool operator!=(REFGUID guidOne, REFGUID guidOther)
{
    return !(guidOne == guidOther);
}
#endif

struct Initializable : public GUID
{
    explicit
        Initializable(char const (&spec)[37])
        : GUID()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            Data1 = (Data1 << 4) | nybble_from_hex(spec[i]);
        }
        assert(spec[8] == '-');
        for (int i = 9; i < 13; ++i)
        {
            Data2 = (Data2 << 4) | nybble_from_hex(spec[i]);
        }
        assert(spec[13] == '-');
        for (int i = 14; i < 18; ++i)
        {
            Data3 = (Data3 << 4) | nybble_from_hex(spec[i]);
        }
        assert(spec[18] == '-');
        for (int i = 19; i < 23; i += 2)
        {
            Data4[(i - 19) / 2] = (nybble_from_hex(spec[i])<<4) | nybble_from_hex(spec[i+1]);
        }
        assert(spec[23] == '-');
        for (int i = 24; i < 36; i += 2)
        {
            Data4[2 + (i - 24) / 2] = (nybble_from_hex(spec[i]) << 4) | nybble_from_hex(spec[i + 1]);
        }
    }
};

template<class T>
inline
auto __my_uuidof()
-> GUID const &
{
    return GUID_NULL;
}

#define CPPX_GNUC_UUID_FOR( name, spec )            \
template<>                                          \
inline                                              \
auto __my_uuidof<name>()                            \
    -> GUID const&                                  \
{                                                   \
    using ::operator"" _uuid;                       \
    static GUID the_uuid = spec ## _uuid;           \
                                                    \
    return the_uuid;                                \
}                                                   \
                                                    \
template<>                                          \
inline                                              \
auto __my_uuidof<name*>()                           \
    -> GUID const&                                  \
{ return __my_uuidof<name>(); }                     \
                                                    \
static_assert( true, "" )

auto operator"" _uuid(char const* const s, size_t const size) 
-> GUID
{
    return Initializable(reinterpret_cast<char const (&)[37]>(*s));
}

#define CPPX_UUID_FOR    CPPX_GNUC_UUID_FOR

#define __uuid(T)       __my_uuidof<T>()

struct Foo {};
CPPX_UUID_FOR(Foo, "dbe41a75-d5da-402a-aff7-cd347877ec00");

Foo foo;

template <class T>
void QueryInterface(T** p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return;

    GUID guid = "dbe41a75-d5da-402a-aff7-cd347877ec00"_uuid;
    if (__uuid(T) == guid)
    {
        *p = &foo;
    }
    else
    {
        *p = NULL;
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    Foo* p = NULL;
    QueryInterface(&p);

    cout << "p: " << p << ", &foo: " << &foo << endl;   

    return 0;
}
```

Saved it to uuidtest.cpp, and I used g++-7 to compile it successfully (other gcc with c++11/14 support may also work well), and run well:

```
g++-7 uuidtest.cpp -o uuidtest
./uuidtest
p: 0x6021c0, &foo: 0x6021c0
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe typeid will work

Else,
You can use a reinterpret_cast.

```
For exemple here we have the class A;

A * ex;
ex = reinterpret_cast<A>(*pv);
if (ex == NULL)
{
  //Do some stuff
  //this means **ex** isn't a A class
}
```

It'll work on all classes that inherit from A.

Comment: sorry, my bad, i edited my post

Comment: The key point is how to return the uuid of one interface inherited from IUnknown, I think your code can't catch it.

Comment: During my studies, typeid wasn't allowed, i used to make reinterpret_cast in this case.

Comment: I think you made some silly typos in your answer. You should try out your solution on [ideone](http://ideone.com) or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com) to make sure it works.