# Get UUID of struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, uuid

**Background**

I have an [IDL file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367062(v=vs.85).aspx) that defines a number of `struct` like so

```
typedef[uuid(68D81983-793D-43BE-AC16-C74254C90607)] struct Foo
{
    // some members
} Foo;
```

When compiled (using Visual Studio 2013) it generates a `.h` file where the corresponding `struct` gets translated to

```
typedef /* [uuid] */ DECLSPEC_UUID("68D81983-793D-43BE-AC16-C74254C90607") struct Foo
{
    // some members
} Foo;
```

The macro `DECLSPEC_UUID` expands to

```
#define DECLSPEC_UUID(x)    __declspec(uuid(x))
```

**Question**

How can I retrieve the UUID of this `struct` elsewhere?

After including the generated header, I've tried to use [`__uuidof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaah6a61(v=vs.120).aspx)

```
static const auto idFoo = __uuidof(Foo);
```

But then I get a compilation error

```
error C2787: 'Foo' : no GUID has been associated with this object
```

Comment: I don't know enough to mark this a duplicate, but this answer seems to cover this in great deatil:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977244/how-can-i-define-an-uuid-for-a-class-and-use-uuidof-in-the-same-way-for-g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be trying to declare and `typedef` the `struct` at the same time.

```
typedef[uuid(68D81983-793D-43BE-AC16-C74254C90607)] struct Foo
{
    // some members
} Foo;
```

The solution is to declare the `struct`, then seperately `typedef` it. Then `__uuidof` works with no issues.

```
[uuid(68D81983-793D-43BE-AC16-C74254C90607)] struct Foo
{
    // some members
};
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```